# KooBoo & Servicestack Architecture / Design questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, servicestack, kooboo

I wanna use [KooBoo](http://www.kooboo.com/) for my web platform and for that combine it with Servicestack ([Servicestack](http://www.servicestack.net)).
Servicestack should act as the REST API framework and Kooboo as the user frontend framework.

I would like to build a independent service layer within that, where Kooboo controllers and servicestack services are leliyng on and share for instance the same session.

So my questions are

1. How to integrate a webservice framework in Kooboo in general (Change
   source, Module, Plugin...)
2. How to use / integrate layered architecture ? (Because you persist Models directly with your data API, is there a way or what is the recommended way of usinf business objects and ViewModels separated)
3. Can I integrate other editors instead of tinyMCE
4. When I use other js framworks like angularJS or kendoUI, can I still use the "inline edit" functions ?

I know, a lot of questions. If you want me to split up these into separate threads I will do that of course!

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of KooBoo before but seeing that it's built on ASP.NET MVC, the [ServiceStack Integration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-Integration) and [MVC Integration docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration) shows how you can access ServiceStack's dependencies, plugins, execute Services etc. from outside of ServiceStack, e.g from within ASP.NET MVC.

The documentation goes through to explain different ways you can integrate with ServiceStack from an ASP.NET MVC web application and also includes a live demo of different techniques at http://mvc.servicestack.net ([source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/tree/master/src/Mvc)).